# ¿Cómo convertir una string a int en c++?

Tags: c++

Suponiendo que tengo una variable string con la cadena de texto de un número hexadecimal ¿Cómo puedo guardarla en un número?

```
string n = "0X54";
int a = int(n);
int b = static_cast<int>(n);
```

Me arroja el error: `invalid cast from type ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ to type ‘int’`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A partir del estándar C++11 existe la función `stoi`, a la cual se puede acceder incluyendo la cabecera `<string>`.

Dicha función en su forma más general tiene la signatura:

```
int stoi (const string&  str, size_t* idx = 0, int base = 10);
```

Para tu ejemplo, ya que tu cadena contiene un número hexadecimal, es suficiente con cambiar el último parámetro (que por default es para números en base 10) al valor 16.

En consecuencia, esto debería servirte:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    string n = "0x54";
    int a = stoi(n, nullptr, 16);
    cout << a << '\n'; //muestra en la consola el valor 84.
    return 0;
}
```

Para más referencia puedes revisar el siguiente [enlace](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/) (en inglés).

Comment: Muchas gracias. Esto me funcionó perfecto.

Answer (score 7):

El error que recibes es claro y conciso: No se puede convertir un `std::string` a `int`. La conversión que has usado (`static_cast`) es una conversión de tipos; esta conversión sólo permite las conversiones entre ciertos tipos fundamentales, conversiones con clases que dispongan de operadores de conversión, o conversiones entre clases que estén relacionadas mediante herencia. Para `std::string` e `int` no se cumple ninguno de los casos mencionados.

---

C++ dispone de al menos tres herramientas para convertir una cadena de caracteres en un valor numérico, a parte del (ya [mencionado por Xam](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/187737/2742)) [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) (`s`tring `to` `i`nteger) disponemos de la lectura con formato de `std::stringstream`:

```
std::stringstream ss{"0X54"};
int valor;
ss >> std::hex >> valor;
std::cout << valor; // Muestra 84.
```

En el código anterior, le hemos indicado a `std::stringstream` que íbamos a leer un valor hexadecimal (`std::hex`) en una variable de tipo `int`; funcionaría con cualquier tipo de dato integral.

También (desde C++17) disponemos de [`std::from_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars), que convierte a número una secuencia cerrada de valores:

```
char OX54[]{"0X54"};
int valor;
std::from_chars(std::begin(OX54), std::end(OX54), valor, 16);
std::cout << valor; // Muestra 84.
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta y los enlaces a la documentación, sin duda estos ejemplos me serán muy útiles.

Comment: +1 por la función `from_chars`. Siempre se aprende algo nuevo!