# ¿Cómo convertir un número de tipo de dato string a un tipo de dato int en C++?

Tags: c++, string, conversión-de-tipos, math

Me preguntaba cómo puedo convertir un número que esté en tipo de dato string al mismo número pero en tipo de dato int.

Por ejemplo, digamos que tenemos   `string numeroString = "1234";` y luego quiero que ese mismo número (utilizando otra variable) se convierta en tipo de dato int, como si luego fuera  `int numeroInt = 1234;`

Sé que es posible convertir cualquier número a un string con `to_string()` , pero no sé cómo hacerlo al contrario.

Gracias por su ayuda!

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/187734/c%C3%B3mo-convertir-una-string-a-int-en-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fíjate si lo puedes lograr con la función `atoi`. Esta función Analiza la cadena tipo string e interpreta su contenido como un número entero, que se devuelve como un valor de tipo int.
Para utilizar la función atoi necesitamos llamar la librería cstdlib #include . Y la sintaxis es la siguiente.

```
atoi(variableString.c_str());
```

[Explicación de la función atoi](https://yosoy.dev/como-convertir-cadena-entero-en-c/#:%7E:text=Para%20convertir%20nuestra%20cadena%20a,un%20valor%20de%20tipo%20int.)

Answer (score 1):

Esa conversión se hace con `atoi` https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atoi.htm